# In XPath, how can I select groups of following-sibling nodes before and after an anchor element?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have a xml document like follows,

```
<sec>
    <p type="Running">aa</p>
    <p type="heading 1">bb</p>
    <p type="body">cc</p>
    <p type="body">dd</p>
    <p type="Running">ee</p>
    <p type="Body">ff</p>
    <p type="heading">gg</p>
    <p type="body">hh</p>
    <p type="body">ii</p>
    <p type="Running">jj</p>
    <p type="list">kk</p>
    <p type="list">ll</p>
    <p type="list">mm</p>
    <p type="list">nn</p>
</sec>
```

using xpath I need to select consecutive following-siblings of `<p>` nodes from `<p>` that has attr value of `Running`.

SO in above example

```
    <p type="heading 1">bb</p>
    <p type="body">cc</p>
    <p type="body">dd</p>
```

and

```
    <p type="Body">ff</p>
    <p type="heading">gg</p>
    <p type="body">hh</p>
    <p type="body">ii</p>
```

and

```
    <p type="list">kk</p>
    <p type="list">ll</p>
    <p type="list">mm</p>
    <p type="list">nn</p>
```

node groups should be selected.

How can I write a XPath query to select those nodes?

```
XPath version - 2.0
```

Comment: @Abel ,  Thanks for the advice. :) I'm new to XSLT and concepts of XSLT is bit different that other languages (oop) that I'm familiar with. . I'm trying harder to understand there concepts asap.

Comment: That is good to hear, and yes, functional, declarative programming can be quite a leap from OOP, but most people only require a few hours of courses to get the hang of it. [Dimitre Novatchev made an excellent online course on XSLT Foundations](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/xslt-foundations-part1), even just following the first hour will already make you understand XSLT and how templates work much better and it'll save you hours, even days of frustration and more importantly, will speed up your development time.

Comment: @Abel ,  Thanks for sharing the tutorial. and yeh.. agreed with your point. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question currently has three answers, but I don't think any of them actually answers the question.

In XPath 2.0, everything is sequences. If you select a set of nodes, in XPath 1.0 you called that a "node set", in XPath 2.0 it is a "sequence of nodes". One property of sequences is that they cannot be nested: `(1, (2, 3), 4)` is the same as `(1, 2, 3, 4)`.

You ask for a select statement that selects sets of nodes, which implies that you want to do something with each set. The logical thing to do is something like the following:

```
for $r in sec/p[@type = 'Running']
return $r
    /following-sibling::p
    [not(@type = 'Running')]
    [. << following-sibling::p[@type = 'Running'][1]]
```

This is a rather complex expression. While it will internally select the subsets you are after, because of sequence normalization, the net effect is a single sequence with a selection equal to `sec/p[not(@type = 'Running')]`.

In XPath 2.0 it is not possible to do this differently, so the natural thing to do then is to use a host language, like XSLT or XQuery, to select the `@type = 'Running'` nodes, and on each hit, select (and do something) will the following siblings until the next `@type = 'Running'`:

```
<xsl:template match="sec">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="p[@type = 'Running']" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <!-- do something before the group -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::p[following-sibling::p[@type = 'Running'] >> .]" mode="group"/>
    <!-- do something after the group -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p" mode="group">
   <!-- do something with items in the group -->
</xsl:template>
```

It is probably easier to use an `xsl:for-each-group` here, which is meant for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know XPath 2, but with XPath 1 and a bit of higher-level programming, you can use this kind of XPath expressions, counting preceding siblings with type="Running":

```
//p[not(@type="Running")
    and count(preceding-sibling::p[@type="Running"])=1]
                                                     ^
                                                     |
                                                1 then 2 then 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Xpath select everything except type='Running'

```
/sec/p[not(@type='Running')]
```

Answer (score -2):

This should help you -

```
var j = new List<string>();
var t = new XmlDocument();
t.Load(new StreamReader("xmlPath"));
var type = t.GetElementsByTagName("p");

for (var i = 0; i < type.Count; i++)
{
    if (((XmlNode)type[i]).Attributes[0].Value != "Running")
    {
       j.Add(((XmlNode)type[i]).OuterXml);
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes a generic programming language, while the question is about XPath. Besides, this solution does not group the items in any way by the elements between the `Running` elements, nor does it return a set of nodes.