# Extracting subsets of sequences with XPath

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I'm looking for an XPATH to extract 'sets' as separate sequences. It has to be interpreted by python `lxml` (which is a wrapper around `libxml2`).

For example, given the following:

```
<root>
    <sub1>
        <sub2>
            <Container>
                <item>1 - My laptop has exploded again</item>
                <item>2 - This is an issue which needs to be fixed.</item>
            </Container>
        </sub2>
        <sub2>
            <Container>
                <item>3 - It's still not working</item>
                <item>4 - do we have a working IT department or what?</item>
            </Container>
        </sub2>
        <sub2>
            <Container>
                <item>5 - Never mind - I got my 8 year old niece to fix it</item>
            </Container>
        </sub2>
    </sub1>
</root>
```

I want to be able to 'isolate' each group or sequence, e.g. sequence 1 being:

```
1 - My laptop has exploded again
2 - This is an issue which needs to be fixed.
```

Second sequence:

```
3 - It's still not working
4 - do we have a working IT department or what?
```

Third sequence:

```
5 - Never mind - I got my 8 year old niece to fix it
```

Where 'sequence' would be, translated in pseudocode/python:

```
seq1 = ['1 - My laptop has exploded again', '2 - This is an issue which needs to be fixed.']
seq2 = ['3 - It's still not working', '4 - do we have a working IT department or what?']
seq 3 = ['5 - Never mind - I got my 8 year old niece to fix it']
```

From some preliminary research it seems like [sequences can't be nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32732003/in-xpath-how-can-i-select-groups-of-following-sibling-nodes-before-and-after-an) but I'm wondering if there's some black magic doable with [these operators](http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html#Pages~List_of_XPaths).

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *sequence*?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan I've added a clarification

Comment: Alright, I've added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Evaluate this XPath expression:

   `count(/*/*/*)`

This finds the number of `<sub2>` elements (equivalent and more readable, but longer, is:

```
count(/*/sub1/sub2))
```

2. For each `$n` in 1 to `count(/*/*/*)` evaluate the following XPath expression:

   `/*/*/*[$n]/*/item/text()`

Again, this is equivalent to the longer and more readable:

```
/*/sub1/sub2[$n]/Container/item/text()
```

Before evaluating the above expressions replace `$n` with the actual value of `$n` (for example using the `format()` method for strings.

For the provided XML document `$n` is 3, therefore the actual XPath expressions that are evaluated are:

```
/*/*/*[1]/*/item/text()
```

,

```
/*/*/*[2]/*/item/text()
```

,

```
/*/*/*[3]/*/item/text()
```

And they produce the following results each:

A collection (language - dependent -- array, sequence, collection, `IEnumerable<string>`, ... etc.):

```
"1 - My laptop has exploded again", "2 - This is an issue which needs to be fixed."
```

,

```
"3 - It's still not working", "4 - do we have a working IT department or what?"
```

,

```
"5 - Never mind - I got my 8 year old niece to fix it"
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks very interesting. So to recap - given an unbounded number of what you refer as 'n', I'd have to combine the output of 'count' with an array selector so that I can pick the right list..?

Comment: @lorenzog, I have been using Python in the past and I don't remember details. I can give you C# code, or pseudo-code: `for (var i = 1 to n){var expression = string.Format("/*/*/*[{0}]/*/item/text()", i); var sequence = Evaluate(expression);}

Comment: What I meant was - can you iterate through expressions with xpath? For the rest language is not a problem - in fact I tried it with xpaths and it works, so now I have to use python to iterate twice; once of the 'counting' XPath, then for each element.

Comment: @lorenzog, You cannot achieve this with a single XPath 1.0 or XPath 2.0 / 3.0 expression. In XPath 3.1 there is a standard data type *array*, whose items can be sequences. But I doubt lxml has even XPath 2.0 support. So, your present solution is the best you can achieve, without having XPath 3.1 support. You can "iterate through expressions" with XPath 2.0/3.0 but the result will be a single sequence, because a sequence cannot be nested.

Comment: yep looks like it -- https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-sequence-expressions says "Sequences are never nested—for example, combining the values 1, (2, 3), and ( ) into a single sequence results in the sequence (1, 2, 3)." so that's it

Answer (score 0):

```
from lxml import etree

doc=etree.parse("data.xml");
v = doc.findall('sub1/sub2/Container')
finalResult = list()
for vv in v:
    sequence = list()
    for item in vv.findall('item'):
        sequence.append(item.text)
    finalResult.append(sequence)
print finalResult
```

And this is the result:

```
[['1 - My laptop has exploded again', '2 - This is an issue which needs to be fixed.'], ["3 - It's still not working", '4 - do we have a working IT department or what?'], ['5 - Never mind - I got my 8 year old niece to fix it']]
```

#### Note

I assumed that the data is in a file named 'data.xml' in the same directory as the script that contains the above code.

Comment: Yes I think I'll have to resort to something similar. I was hoping in a pure XPATH expression..

Comment: @lorenzog  The xpath gives you a list of text , but you want a list of list